# Is there a way to install all npm dependencies globally (centrally) so that you do not store node_modules in the project folder?

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-install

This is causing problems with my computer as I have over 40 projects each with their own node_modules folder, packed with millions of 1kb files.

I am currently deleting my old projects and I found that the node modules folders take up a considerable amount of space. Seems silly to repeat the installations, also explains where the precious free space of my tiny SSD went.

Is there a solution for this?

Comment: You can install them globally with the -g flag, but then you need to `npm link` all of them, which quickly gets tedious and very error-prone.  Hopefully somebody else has a better solution.

Comment: I don't think npm is designed for this. You might include it as a feature request for the yarn package manager, though. One thing you might try (at your own risk) is symlinking all `node_modules` directories to a single folder, then running your installs. Not sure how the dependency graphs will work out.

Comment: @jedd.ahyoung There is already a [feature request for Yarn](https://github.com/yarnpkg/yarn/issues/499).

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30209238/install-package-json-dependencies-globally